# the last 25 yards

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't quite understand the phrase "the last 25 yards"? Can it be "the last 12 yards"? Is the number 25 special in English?

> One of the most pressing issues is moving vaccines from freezers into arms. Osterholm says the Trump administration’s Operation Warp Speed deserves “tremendous credit” for investing $11 billion into the R&D and acquisition of vaccines, but adds that its officials didn’t properly organize and fund the final stage. “They built this bridge that was incredible for 1280 yards, but they forgot the last 25 yards,” he says. “That doesn’t work very well.”

> Source:  Science

Comment: It seems to suggest that the figure of 1305 yards (1280 + 25) has some special significance, but I have no idea what this might be.

Comment: The last mile is also used with the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no special meaning.  Any small number would be the same.

The only special yardage I can thing of is the phrase "the whole nine yards", which you hear occasionally.